# In python 3, how to make a tuple which is one object, as many objects as there are elements in the tuple? It shall be valid as function parameter

Tags: python, tuples

Let's say I have the *python* function `f(x, y)` and a tuple `t = (a, b)`. To apply `f` to `t`, I can write `f(t[0], t[1])` which is not elegant, especially if the size of the tuple is greater than 2.

`f` is not my function and I don't want to manage any customisation of the module it comes from. So a solution as `f(t)` where `f` is modified is not acceptable.

Is there a way to do something like `f(t.elements())` ?

Comment: Have you tried star unpacking `f(*t)`?

Comment: In case that the `t` has more than 2 elements, the function will raise an error. So you should define the function like `f(a, b, *args)` then you will get what  you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `f(*t)`

```
def f(x,y):
    print(x,y)

t = ('Hello','World')

f(*t) #prints out Hello world
```

`*` unpack the values for you